# How to install H.265 / HEVC codec on Ubuntu Linux v17 +

Tags: apt, video, vlc, hevc

I would like to be able to play HEVC files in Ubuntu v18 but I know since version 17 the following plugin is not installable:

```
hutber@hutber ~ $ sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vlc-plugin-libde265
```

Is it possible to get these files working in 18 without having to use the chrome app to play them?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

*gstreamer1.0-libav* supports video/x-h265 (HEVC) in Ubuntu 17.10 and later in Totem media player.

H.265 is the successor to H.264 which gstreamer1.0-libav also supports in Ubuntu 17.10 and later. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-libav
```

Comment: Thanks Karel... One question, which player would I use to use this codec?

Comment: Forgive me Karel, but I do already have VLC installed. But can't find anywhere to set the player to use `gstreamer`.

Comment: I have updated the question with images of my settings

Comment: gstreamer1.0-libav only is used by gtreamer apps like totem. Vlc & mpv support hevc thru ffmpeg libraries and will play out of the box.

Comment: @doug - You should consider posting your comment as an answer saying that with most and best players (vlc, mpv, smplayer, gnome-mpv) that package is not needed. First of all, the basic question is whether that codec is needed or not; and second the OP seem to prefer VLC.

Comment: uninstalling the package, mpv, smplayer, vlc and kaffeine can still play HEVC samples from https://x265.com/hevc-video-files/

Comment: VLC certainly doesn't support it out of the box :p I'm on version 4 and still the video does not play. The video comes up, but it will only display 1 frame and then not move. I know that it is not my hardware as it works perfectly when in Potplayer on windows

Comment: Humm ok, the trial videos work given on that page... But I am using gopro hero6 and the files are certainly HEVC and 1080 240fps

Comment: Oh, it seems if I pass the following to VLC it works a lot better: `--avcodec-threads=12 --avcodec-hw=none --rate=0.90`